# Is there a way to identify whether a web page has finished loading content using android accessibility api?

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I want to use Accessibility API to detect the contents in any web browser applications in Android. I am familiar with the events TYPE_WINDOW_CONTENT_CHANGED and TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED, but i am looking for a way to detect contents on page when it has completed loading. Is this possible?